# How to "Tag" csv with kmeans clusters?

Tags: python, scipy

My python code reads a csv and extracts the latitude longitudes and runs them through kmeans. I have a "placeName" field associated with each latitude longitude. My issue is I want to be able to write out a new csv file or somehow tag the data so that I can see which csv row is associated with which cluster. How can I accomplish this when coordinates of kmeans takes in an array, but no properties like "name" or "id"?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2, whiten

coordinates= np.array([
           [lat, long],
           [lat, long],
            ...
           [lat, long]
           ])
x, y = kmeans2(whiten(coordinates), 3, iter = 20)  
plt.scatter(coordinates[:,0], coordinates[:,1], c=y);
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to get is: a list of labels that shows which cluster a coordinate belonging to.
Now you get `x` and `y` both in 2-d arrays.
You can get the label list by first mapping each element in `x` in to a label, and then apply that label mapping to `y`.

```
label = {(x[i,0], x[i,1]):i for i in range(x.shape[0])}
cluster_ids = [label[(a[0],a[1])] for a in y]
```

The `cluster_ids` is the wanted cluster id list.